# Change button color on single target

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project (Portable) and see that the colors on one target (UWP) aren't that good. I want to change the color of a button on that target only, but I can't find how to do that.

I've looked at the files, but it seems to load the whole `LoadApplication(new TheApp.App());` as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Device](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/device/) to customize properties per platform

```
myButton.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;

// on Windows only, change color
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows) {
  myButton.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

Comment: Xamarin Forms should extend Device.OnPlatform to include more platforms

Comment: @YuriS Thanks for the information! That might come in handy as well.